# iOS 7 - can I change the delete button background colour in the UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

So I've been studying this for a while and it looks as though it was a big job to change anything to do with the default view for editing a table row.

I just want to change the background colour to something more in line with my app in iOS 7. Can this be done without subclassing?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi, please use the apple developer forum for IOS7 related question. IOS7 is under NDA up to launch date

Comment: Whao, what a great help, given https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/swtableviewcell

[image]